# Can't create static block in Magento

Tags: magento

Well I have static block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_promotion" show_total="3" name="product_featureds" as="product_featureds" template="catalog/product/bestsellers.phtml"}}
```

It works.
Now I try to make similar block with little changes.
I copy *file `core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Promotion.php`*
to
*`core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Randomize.php`*.

Change name of class to *`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Randomize`*.

Copy *`/theme/template/catalog/product/bestsellers.phtml`* to *`/theme/template/catalog/product/randomize.phtml`*.

And try to create static block "randomize" on `admin panel:`

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_randomize" name="product_randomize" num_products="3" template="catalog/product/randomize.phtml"}}
```

It does not work? When I change block type back -- everything is OK.
Whats wrong with my Randomize.php? It looks absolutely the same as Promotion.php.

To show I use this construction:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('randomize')->toHtml();
```

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly the block permision issue

> 1-Goto System > Permissions > Blocks
>
> 2.Add new Block
>
> - Block Name-catalog/product_list_randomize
> - Is Allowed-Yes

Comment: Yes! Thanks. That is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

> core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Promotion.php to
>   core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Randomize.php.

**Do NOT modify CORE function**! Override this function in custom module

Comment: I don't modify. It is a new Class. But maybe I should move it to local?

Comment: Yes, move it to local